# Store git repo in database

Tags: database, git, blob, libgit2

Is there a way to store an entire git repository in a binary blob or a single file?
Basically I am thinking of storing git repos in a database (like a key value store or a relational database), and I need the whole repo to be one blob,

One possible solution is to compress (zip) all the repo structure,

Any built in facility that I may have looked over?

libgit2 by any chance helps in this regard?

EDIT: to make it clear: I have lots and lots of git repos and I want to be able to access them from different machines, apps. My application is nothing like that, but think github.

Comment: What's your reason for wanting to do this?  Is it for backup purposes?  Not sure what you're hoping to gain by doing this.

Comment: I have lots and lots of them and I want to be able to access them from different machines, apps. My application is nothing like that, but think github,

Comment: The "obvious" way to create a usable blob from a git repo would be using `git bundle`. That said, I agree with Nick that some more information about the use case is more likely to produce a helpful answer.

Comment: @TimoGeusch `git bundle` looks promising.

Comment: @Ali "I have lots and lots of git repos and I want to be able to access them from different machines, apps." - you ain't need no database for that. Install a git server, and you will have proper Git access through SSH. That's **the** way you should do it.

Comment: @H2CO3 basically you are suggesting use a file server not a database server, What if I needed replication, and readonly replicas, and all the things that come with a database server? and I didn't need ssh access? by the way very cool username.

Comment: If you're trying to actually do distributed content manangement, having a single binary of the repo will be a HUGE limitation... Think about how a merge conflict will go or even need to happen. The clients code will need to get the current version, unpack it, setup a remote to that unpacked version in your local repo, do a merge, repack it if it works and reupload. Hell... you're completely defeating the entire purpose of git at that point. @H2CO3 has the correct solution and that is the way these things are normally handled

Comment: @g19fanatic thanks a lot, really appreciate your comment, in my case everything happens on the server(s) side and no client downloading and merging is needed, and client side conflict resolution is needed. Still your comment made me rethink the whole idea, I need more time to decide and maybe benchmark.

Comment: implement your own odb backend to store objects in a relational database! libgit2 supports custom odb backends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, as @TimoGeusch mentioned `git bundle` was what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

> My application is nothing like that, but think github

Take a look at [gitlab](http://gitlab.org/)